# Nuxt input formula input key value pair

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hashmap, nuxt.js

Is there a way to get hashmaps from a form in nuxt?

I'm using nuxt and have a form where I want to receive a hash map where the user is entering a key-value pair that will be parsed to an API.

```html
<template>
  <div class="columns is-gapless is-marginless">
    <div class="column">
      <b-input
        v-model="mapKey"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        @blur="$emit('blur', $event)"
        @focus="$emit('focus', $event)"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b-input
        v-model="mapValue"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        @blur="$emit('blur', $event)"
        @focus="$emit('focus', $event)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MapInput',
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value (value) {
      this.mapKey = this.parseMapKey(value)
      this.mapValue = this.parseMapValue(value)
    },
    mapKey () {
      this.updateValue()
    },
    mapValue () {
      this.updateValue()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    parseMapKey (value) {
      if (value !== undefined && value != null && 'mapKey' in value) {
        return value.mapKey
      } else {
        return ''
      }
    },
    parseMapValue (value) {
      if (value !== undefined && value != null && 'mapValue' in value) {
        return value.mapValue
      } else {
        return ''
      }
    },
    updateValue () {
      this.map.set(this.mapKey, this.mapValue)
      this.$emit('input', { mapKey: this.mapKey, mapValue: this.mapValue })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If I try to use KEY as the key value and VALUE as the value value

it returns `"mapKey": "KEY", "mapValue": "VALUE"`

is it possible to change it so it returns `"KEY":"VALUE"`?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here exactly but maybe give a try to that page: https://javascript.info/object It's called "object" in JS realm and may be far easier to work with than what you have as of right now.

Comment: Well in the end i wanna dynamically change property name (key) depending on user input